# API Design: images with multiple i18n titles

Tags: rest, api, internationalization, api-design

We're designing an API where partners can post images and titles with it. I do have some trouble imaging how to implement an API endpoint for it which supports i18n in the most **uncomplicated** way for our partners (not remembering our returned ids for example if they want to use their existing ids).

Our first database table idea looked like:

```
image_id | partner_id | category_id | image | description 
---------------------------------------------------------
 123     | 1          | 8           | url.. | This is my image!
 234     | 2          | 5           | url.. | A pretty image.
```

But we would probably split the description into an own table which would look something like:

```
image_id | language | description 
---------------------------------
123      | en       | This is my image!
123      | de       | Dies ist mein Bild!
```

So how could the API endpoint look like?

1. Single request with an array of images, which can be the same images just with different language/description values? (images would not be persisted multiple times, just the different descriptions)
2. N requests with images and an `Content-Language` header for all the images contained inside the request? (resulting in the same persistence as in the 1. idea)
3. Single request to create images with a *"default"* language/description value and a PUT endpoint to further add additional language/description values?
4. Something completely different?

Comment: I must admit, I still don't get your use case. Are you creating an image store? How titles will be used? BTW. Ich denke "Das ist mein Bild", aber mein Deutsch is leider nicht am besten.

Comment: Providers will send images to us. We're displaying the images with their titles in a small gallery (currently the titles are only displayed in german and englisch, but i18n is planned).

PS: You can use "das" or "dies" in that sentence. :)